# Looking to add a twitctv feed to my site

Tags: java, html, module

I need to add a feed from Twicth TV to my website, so that when a game is played from our account, it will show on a small screen on my site.  Do I need java to do this?  When I googled it there was reference of a 'module'. Not sure what this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript+JQuery you can easily poll for your channel's JSON and then extract if your channel is online or not.

```
var chan = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel={YourChannelName}&jsonp=?";
$.getJSON(chan, function(json)
{
    try
    {
        var check = json[0].channel.channel_url == "http://www.justin.tv/{YourChannelName}";
        $("#twitch_stream").css({"display":"block"});
    }
    catch (err)
    {
    }
});
```

Then you use this as the embedded code.  Make sure autoplay is turned off so then people won't hear ads in the background when the channel isn't live.

```
<div id="twitch_stream" style="display:none";>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel={YourChannelName}" bgcolor="#000000" >
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel={YourChannelName}&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: is the justin tv site just an example link or do i go through them ?

Comment: do i need jquery library for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Curl for this.

You can read more about it here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php